# Changing the text on a label by activating button

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to change the label text by pressing the "+" button, but if I run the program it is already changed to "testok" instead of "test" at start. So my question is why?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
var = "test"
label = Label(root, text=var)
label.pack()
button_plus = Button(root, text="+", command=label.config(text=var + "ok"))
button_plus.pack()
button_minus = Button(root, text="-", command=root.destroy)
button_minus.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please mention the programming language. You should tag it to this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Button parameter “command” executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared)

Answer (score 0):

The `command` of `button_plus` is assigned the result of `label.config(text=var+"ok")` which is `None`.  You can use `lambda` to do what you want:

```
button_plus = Button(root, text="+", command=lambda: label.config(text=var + "ok"))
```